# How to pass env variables in dataproc submit command?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-submit, dataproc

I want to be able to set the following env variables while submitting a job via dataproc submit:

1. SPARK_HOME
2. PYSPARK_PYTHON
3. SPARK_CONF_DIR
4. HADOOP_CONF_DIR

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is when setting these variables? In general Dataproc will configure the environment for jobs so that e.g. SPARK_HOME is set correctly. Are you trying to override the default locations?

Comment: Thank you @JerryDing for your time :)
Dataproc is not available with pyspark 3.2. Pyspark 3.2.0 released pandas API for pyspark and I have to write our pipelines for it. So, I am creating the cluster with an env yaml that gets pyspark installed as a package in it. Then I am overriding the above-mentioned env variables to use this pyspark 3.2.0.
Please suggest improvements/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Check the doc [Setting environment variables on Dataproc cluster nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207679/setting-environment-variables-on-dataproc-cluster-nodes) on how to set env variables for different components in Dataproc.